# Wso2 Web Services Framework for PHP and issues with ssl client and http sender

Tags: php, web-services, wsdl, wso2

I am using Wso2 Web Services Framework (WSF) for PHP together with Zend Server CE 5.5 and for some reason issues occurs at the end stage of the connection phase to the Web Service.

The Web Service (built in .NET I believe) accepts calls over HTTPS with no user/password authentication needed and no need for a client certificate. I also make use of WSDL with the WSClient.

So, when connecting, I simply set the parameters below:

```
$settings = array(
    "wsdl" => realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . "/resources/wsdl.xml"),
    "classmap" => $classMap, // classMap maps the WSDL names to corresponding PHP classes
    "CACert" => realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . "/resources/cert.pem"),
    "timeout" => 40,
    "useSOAP" => "1.2",
    "useWSA" => 1.0
);
```

The policy found inside the WSDL is the following:

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="BasicHttpBinding_IApplication_policy" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <wsp:ExactlyOne>
    <wsp:All>
      <sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
        <wsp:Policy>
          <sp:TransportToken>
            <wsp:Policy>
              <sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="false"/>
            </wsp:Policy>
          </sp:TransportToken>
          <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
            <wsp:Policy>
              <sp:Basic256/>
            </wsp:Policy>
          </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
          <sp:Layout>
            <wsp:Policy>
              <sp:Strict/>
            </wsp:Policy>
          </sp:Layout>
        </wsp:Policy>
      </sp:TransportBinding>
    </wsp:All>
  </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

In the `wsf_php_client.log` I find that no connection is made, but it's difficult to pinpoint exactly where the issue lies. Is the `[info]` line in the log what initiates the `[error]` later?

```
[warning] msg_ctx.c(1384) RampartClientConfiguration not set in message context
[info]  [ssl client] Client certificate chain filenot specified
[error] http_sender.c(1355) Error occurred in transport
[error] engine.c(171) Transport sender invoke failed
[error] wso2-wsf-php-src-2.1.0/src/wsf_wsdl.c(1226) [wsf_wsdl] Response envelope not found
```

At every stage, everything looks fine. I've had a look at the data returned by the function `wsf_process_wsdl` in `wsf_wsdl.php` and the data gathered looks fine.

I've dug through most wso2 forum threads that seem to at least touch my problem, but nothing is corresponding exactly to this. I'm really running out of options to where the issue lies and how to solve it. Am I missing something when setting up WSClient with its settings array?

Comment: Digging a bit further down, and adding some additional debug output to the WSF source, I get http status code 415 from the web service. My theory is that it has something to do with the content-type sent. Testing with the ws.js module for nodejs, I got it working with content-type `text/xml`, and got status code 415 if I tried sending it as `application/soap+xml`.

Answer (score 0):

text/xml is the content type for SOAP 1.1 , and application/soap+xml is the content type for soap1.2 , Since you are setting the soap version as soap12, the message is likely to be sent as a soap12 message.

From the error you have specified, it looks to me like the message failed to get to the endpoint. Can you check whether the endpoint specified in the wsdl is correct. Or you could specify the endpoint in the client options array.